# Gas / baseboard heating should be on but it's not -- how to investigate?

Tags: heating, gas, heat

This is my first Winter in this house and I've just realized that I can't make the heat turn on. The home has natural gas heating and baseboard vents. There's no A/C or other units; just baseboard heating.

I'll pay a pro to come out if I have to, but I just want to make sure that I check everything obvious first, since this probably would've come up in the home inspection if there were really something wrong with the heater.

Here's a list of what's been checked:

1. Thermostat -- seems to work fine and is a very simple electronic model. Heat is set to ON with a (desired) temperature of 71, but actual temperature shows as 55. I tried turning it on and off, up and down, etc.
2. Water -- hot water works fine.
3. Emergency shutoff switch -- heat is set to ON. Tried turning it off and on.
4. Other valves / pipes -- I can't figure out which pipes are supposed to connect to the baseboard units, but I made sure that everything I could find was switched on.

I have to admit that I am very ignorant in this area. The same furnace that heats the water is the same one that should be heating the air, right? If so, it seems to be on and working.

This photo has the furnace, water heater, and gas in it:

[image]

You can see the baseboards in the bottom right of this photo:

[image]

Comment: Are the baseboard units hydronic, or...?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm sorry, I don't know. If that means that they use water I *think* so but I'm not sure. The reason I think so is that I don't see anything that looks like an air duct except for one tube going from outside the basement to the furnace, which I assume is for exhaust.

Comment: Can you post photos of the ends of the baseboard units?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sure, I will. In the mean time you can see them here in photos 5, 9, and 23 from this real estate website: https://www.redfin.com/MD/Riviera-Beach/8472-Church-Rd-21122/home/98275121

Comment: Is the hydronic boiler actually firing up and getting hot?

Comment: tIs the pilot light lit? here should be instructions on the side of the furnace explaining how to do this safely.

Comment: Also, is the valve providing gas to the furnace on? It looks like it might be the blue handle on the pipe to the left of the furnace. On should be parallel  to (in line with) the direction of the pipe.

Comment: @bib I tried restarting the pilot. No luck. I think everything is on but I'm not really 100% sure. I can feel some tiny vibration going through all of the pipes like the gas is flowing, but there's a temp gauge on the furnace and it shows it as being 0 degrees...

Comment: Did the pilot actually light? You should be able to see it.

Comment: @bib I can't see anything. I think this one is automatic and presumably inside of the square box. I'm not sure where I'd see it. But I heard something that sounded it though I think. If you look at the pic of the furnace the switch I flipped to automatically turn it on and off is the thing in front of the furnace under where the pipe leads down to a grey thing that has a black switch on top; like 3" or 4" off the ground. Where would I look to see a flame tho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the photos you provided I am sure that your heating system is hydronic, i.e. water is heated by the furnace and then flows through your baseboards giving up its heat to the room.  The unit on the left in your photo is your water heater which operates independently of your heating furnace (the unit on the right).  That's why you can have hot water without room heating. The large cylinder near the top of your furnace is the expansion chamber designed to handle the increase in water pressure as the water is heated by the furnace.  Your problem, however, may be due to the small unit to the right of the expansion chamber, the one with the electrical conduit attached. I believe that is a damper designed to close when the furnace is off to prevent heat being wasted by going up the flue.  When the furnace is on, that damper will be open to allow the gas combustion byproducts to go up the flue.  If that damper is not working properly, and stays closed, the furnace is designed to turn off to prevent those byproducts from filling your basement.  You should check to see if that is your problem.  If your thermostat is asking for heat, and that damper is closed, then the furnace will not run and you will not get heat. One way to cure this problem is simply to disconnect the damper as it does not increase the furnace efficiency very much anyway. Or you can have it replaced.  No guarantees, but this is easy enough to check. Another possibility is that the furnace pilot light is out or the thermocouple is defective.  You probably will need to call a repairman for these problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very knowledgeable answer. I'm going to go investigate this with your answer open on my computer. I will come back and update this thread when I have something to report. I know I heard some faint sounds coming from the square box (the furnace) earlier, so I guess some part of it must be working. I thought that it was heating the water in the water tank, but I guess that must not be the case based on your answer.

Comment: Still no luck. I left a voicemail with an HVAC place. I tried restarting the pilot light (it's automatic -- you flip it off then back on). No luck.  There's a temp gauge on the furnace and it shows it as being 0 degrees...